# Unset Variables from array where Datetime is greater than

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, time

So I been having this issue that I been trying to solve for a while, the issue is that I have an array

```
$time=array("10:00 AM","11:00 AM","12:00 PM","1:00 PM","2:00 PM","3:00 PM","4:00 PM","5:00 PM");
```

and the problem is that I'm trying to u take off the variables of the array if the time now is grater than the value in the array then take off the value from the array else just leave it in there and move on to the next position

This is what I have tried so far

```
$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
$datetime->format('g:i A');

$i=0;
while($i<= count($time)){
    if ($datetime> '12:00 PM') {
      echo "take off time from the array";
    }

    $i++;
}
```

I should end up with a result like this in my array

```
$time=array("1:00 PM","2:00 PM","3:00 PM","4:00 PM","5:00 PM");
```

Comment: First off, `$datetime` is an object, not a formatted time.

Comment: the time is formatted that it will end up `$datetime="9:39 AM"`

Comment: That would be the return value of `$datetime->format('g:i A')` but not the value of `$datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually retrieve the formatted date.

```
$current = $datetime->format('g:i A');
```

then inside the loop, you can use strtotime to convert each to an integer:

```
if ( strtotime($current) > strtotime($time[$i]) ) {
    unset($time[$i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer that was exactly what i need it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$time=array("10:00 AM","11:00 AM","12:00 PM","1:00 PM","2:00 PM","3:00 PM","4:00 PM","5:00 PM");

$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);


//$now = "12:01";
$now = $datetime->format('H:i');


$i=0;
while($i< count($time)){

     $compare = date("H:i", strtotime($time[$i] ));

    if ($now > $compare ) {
      echo "take off time from the array<br />";
      unset($time[$i]);   
    }
    else {
     echo $now ." < ". $compare . "<br />";
    }

    $i++;
}

print_r($time);
```